# Use of undeclared indentifier 'GMSMarker'

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I added #import  to my .h

Why does this XCODE not recognize 'GMSMarker' but does recognize GSMMarkerOptions?

this does not work (from documentation):

```
        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0);
        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
        marker.title = @"Hello World";
        marker.map = mapView_;
```

this works fine:

```
        GMSMarkerOptions *options = [[GMSMarkerOptions alloc] init];
        options.title = @"gsmmarkeroptions does exist";
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have version 1.1.2 of the SDK, but you need to get the latest version 1.2.

In 1.2 `GMSMarkerOptions` was removed, and now you use `GMSMarker` directly.

Comment: I though i was going crazy, did not realize this new update, i got version 1.1.2. like a week ago. I already did not like the approach of markeroptions, good they changed it! Thanks Saxon Druce!